# How to make a table using Angular given a range

Tags: angularjs, range

For example, I have a range 1 to 100. I need to list them in tables like this (3 numbers in a row):

```
1 2 3 

4 5 6

7 8 9

...

...
```

What is the simplest way of doing it in html by using Angular?

Comment: This question really lacks clarity and shows no effort made to resolve issue by presenting code attempts. See; http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask This is a code troubleshooting site ...where's your code?

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question. The answer given by Teliren pretty much answers my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like this

```
var unsortedItems = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

var items = [];

var itemsPerRow = 3;

for(var i =0; i < unsortedItems.length; i++){
    if(i % itemsPerRow === 0){
        items[Math.floor(i / itemsPerRow)] = [unsortedItems[i]];
    } else {
        items[Math.floor(i / itemsPerRow)].push(unsortedItems[i]);
    }
}
```

items will then contain

```
[
    [
        "a", "b", "c"
    ],
    [
        "d", "e"
    ]
]
```

then you can iterate over items on your page

Comment: Thanks, @Teliren. I was wondering whether there is another solution that does not require to create a new array.